# What's a good small hand / electric grinder available on the market?

Tags: ground-coffee, aeropress, grinder

Just transitioned from a coffee shop to an office job, and got a bag of wonderful Counter Culture coffee beans.

New workplace only buys pre-ground coffee and runs it through a Mr. Coffee drip machine. Boo!

I want to buy an Aeropress and start grinding my own coffee beans. I think the fresh coffee will win people over and we can start getting some serious coffee action going on in the office.

Any recommendations for grinders? Looking in the $20-$30 range, but open to anything. Ideally it is small, something I can throw in my backpack on the way to the office, and easy-ish to clean.

Answer (score 4):

I was nearly sure that I have already read the answer somewhere here. I couldn't find it. There might be a duplicate somewhere, or distributed among several answers. Anyway...

**Hand grinders** could be the first option. They're way cheaper, smaller in size, easier to carry, and not noisy in action (nice property for office space). I could mention three nice grinders that I know of. Probably more people may want to add many more nice grinders, but these are the first three I could name. So, no offense please.

- Hario has a nice small one. Skerton ceramic must be the model, I assume.
- Zassenhaus has a very nice hand grinder. I opt for this as it can grind as fine as Turkish. Zassenhaus Havanna is the model name.
- Of course, Sözen is a very very nice hand grinder that you can use for centuries. They have just two models for decades; a carry-on and a table model with the same inner structure.

Then, you can think of **electric grinders**. Lately, I have heard of Baratza Encore a bit too much on the low end side. You may have a look at that.

For sure, there are specialized web sites just for choosing grinders such as [this](http://knowyourgrinder.com).

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the options. I'm taking a look at the models you mentioned. I think the Hario seems like a no-brainer purchase based off it's fantastic reviews, adjustable settings, and lower price. Eventually I'd like to mess around with espresso, but for now I'm going to focus on french press and I think this will do the trick.

Comment: Your welcome @JasonToby. Don't forget that when you're preparing for a party, these will easily make you suffer. However, very nice options to prepare for just two cups in the morning or in the camping. We're not our muscle-built ancestors anymore. :/

Comment: An anonymous request have been made to add Bodum electric grinder to the list. It is said to be producing even grounds. I add it as a comment just for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

When traveling, I use my Hario Skerton grinder. It is slow, and time-consuming, but it does a great job. It does take some serious effort, so I would be tired after grinding for 2 or 3 cups of coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are planning to use it in an office I'd recommend you to get a lower end electric grinder. You'll spend less time grinding beans, which will obviously leave you more time to enjoy your cup of joe during your break.
The Baratza Encore is wonderful, it's quick, the grind is very consistent for a grinder this size and price and the Baratza service is good too. It's ideal for pour-over to French press sized grinds, the espresso grind is less consistent with more fines and boulders.

Alternatively as already mentioned you could get a hand grinder. I have tried and own several. The Hario Mini Mill is for the low price the best you can get. It's in my opinion even better than the Hario Skerton. Especially with the modifications (you can find instructions online) the grind size is very consistent. However you'll easily spend a couple of minutes grinding. If you are willing to spend a bit more, definitely get a Porlex grinder. They are awesome and fit into the Aeropress (the hollow compartment of the plunger) which is very handy for travels and storage. The grind is very consistent, slightly better even than the Hario.

Of course there are many more great alternatives, however they are much higher priced.

Answer (score 0):

For your price range, I can suggest the Hario Skerton - which I've been using myself -

It's kinda slow but I can say that it's probably the best grinder you can buy within that price range.

There is also an upgrade kit for $11 which you can buy from Blue Horse Products.