# What manual grinders are good

Tags: grinder

I already have an old [rok grinder](https://www.rok.coffee/uk/grindergc) and I want to upgrade it, but I am not sure what manual grinders are good. The characteristics that I am looking for are mainly: Consistency of grains and general durability.

Most grinders has the handle at top and when grinding it causes inconsistency of grains. For example in all Hario grinders you will see some grain too fine and others too coarse, you can even move the bottom part of the mill sideways with your hand!

One flaw of rock grinder is a part near the bottom made of plastic (at least in old models), its function is to move the grains while grinding. In my case it broke after a few weeks of use.

The methods in which I usually brew coffee are: Chemex, v60 and woodneck. Some times I also brew in aeropress, eva-solo and ibrik. So it is needed coarse grinding for eva-solo and very fine grinding for ibrik

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's a good small hand / electric grinder available on the market?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/whats-a-good-small-hand-electric-grinder-available-on-the-market)

Comment: Not so sure. Maybe the question is not precise, but Hario, Zassenhaus, and others have the common flaw that their grinding systems leaves some grains coarser and some other finer. Rok grinder has a better grinding system leaving almost no inconsistency. So I want an upgrade too, not a downgrade

Comment: then, you may want to provide more details to cancel out the other hand grinders. You could provide a list of features you want. Otherwise, this question seems like a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I hope this time I have made myself clear. Sorry for the sloppy question

Comment: The inconsistent grinding behavior you're describing in Hario and similar models is related to grind size and occurs mainly when grinding coarsely like for French Press. It might help if you specify your preferred brewing method(s) in the question.

Comment: @RMac Of course, coarser grains implies more inconsistent. I already added some methods